# Multiple wordpress installations on same server

Tags: htaccess

I have three different wordpress sites on my server located like this:

/www -> main site

/www/site2/

/www/site3/

The main site is working but the site2 and site3, which are the wordpress sites inside the folder aren't. I'm getting the following error on site2 and site3, I think it has to do with the htaccess:

`Warning: include(modules/.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/index.php on line 154`

`Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'modules/.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /www/index.php on line 154`

I have the htaccess on /www/site2/ configured like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how should I configure the htaccess?

Comment: If these are new sites (or a new setup) I would highly recommend a WP multi-site install.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network.

Comment: Looks like you're rewriting `/site2` requests -> `/index.php` instead of `/site2/index.php`

Comment: Maybe you can easily add sub domain or another domain on your host and put your WordPress files in them. For example your domain would be Domain.com with default wordpress site and sub1.domain.com could be another site.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess file needs to be updated as follows (change the obvious parts for site3):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I was having similar issues and saw that whenever  I would log in and simply view the permalink settings, the page would work. I later saw that this action is what corrected the .htaccess file.

@jdm2112, I've managed multiple sites without the need for the multisite. I didn't want to consolidate all my data into a single database.